# how can i work with respnse in nifi with InvokeHTTP processor

Tags: apache-nifi

hi i have such a problem, i have a flow that downloads a csv file with data and there are columns like:,system name, surname, phone, mail, card name, proffesion. The file looks like this only data is more of course

| system | name | surname | phone | mail | proffesion | department |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABA | John | Wane | 77777777 | j.wane@gmail.com | accountant | accountancy |
| BCA | Lilly | Black | 89898989 | l.black@gmail.com | recruiter | hr |

I am reading this file record by record and for each record

I need to query another system via REST using first name, last name, profession and department, the query looks something like this:
https://system address/data/?name=${name}&surname=${surname}&proffesion=${proffesion}&department=${department}

I use Invoke HTTP for thisand now this system should return me json with data:{"date": [{"name": "John","surname": "Wane","profession": "ACC","department":"ACC01"}}As you can see in the answer I get a different profession and department. How can I now create a json for each record that will contain data from the csv file, i.e. system, name, surname, phone mail, but proffesion and department will take the response from the second system that came with jason? So that I have the following result:

```
{"system": "ABA",(data from csv)
"phone": 7777777,(data from csv)
"mail": "j.wane@gmail.com" (data from csv)
```

```
"name": "John", (data from csv)
"surname": "Wane", (data from csv)
"profession": "ACC", (data from json response from other system)
"department":"ACC01" (data from json from other system)}
```

**In a word, how can I combine the data from the input csv file with the data coming from the response from another system?**

I try use Invoke HHTP processor to query another system with REST but I don't know what next?

how should i handle getting a response?

Comment: you can put original content into an attribute using ExtractText. or you can keep original content in a parallel queue and  then use mergecontent to join original content with new one.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the use case correctly, you likely want [LookupRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.23.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.LookupRecord/index.html) with a [RestLookupService](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-lookup-services-nar/1.23.0/org.apache.nifi.lookup.RestLookupService/index.html), if you set the `Record Result Contents` property to `Insert Record Fields` it should overwrite the existing `profession` and `department` fields with the results from the lookup. For more complex enrichments take a look at [ForkEnrichment](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.23.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ForkEnrichment/index.html) and [JoinEnrichment](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.23.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoinEnrichment/index.html).